# Constant map iterator won't set to mymap.begin()

Tags: c++, dictionary, iterator, constants

```
map<string,Shopable*>::iterator it = mymap.begin();
```

The iterator appears to be constant, but `items.begin()` doesn't return a constant iterator. Or, that's what I ***think*** because the mouseover error is something like:

```
"No conversion from 'std::Tree_const_iterator<...> to std::Tree_iterator<...> exists'".
```

Why?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `const_iterator` as :

```
map<string,Shopable*>::const_iterator it = mymap.begin();
```

From the error, its clear that `mymap.begin()` returns `const_iterator`. That is because `mymap` is `const` in the function where you've written this, something like following:

```
void f(const std::map<int,int> & m)
{    //^^^^^ note this

      std::map<int,int>::const_iterator it = m.begin(); //m is const in f()
                       //^^^^^ note this
}

void g(std::map<int,int> & m)
{
      std::map<int,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); //m is non-const in g()
}
```

That is, `const` container (whether its `std::map`, `std::vector` etc) returns  `const_iterator` and non-const container returns `iterator`.

Every container has overloaded functions of `begin()` and `end()`. So `const` container invokes the overloaded `begin()` which returns `const_iterator` and non-const container invokes the other overloaded `begin()` which returns `iterator`. And same for `end()` overloaded functions.

Comment: Why would it return a `const_iterator`? All the examples I have seen return just `iterator`.

Comment: std::map.begin() also has an overload which returns an `iterator`. See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/map/begin/

Comment: @Pig Head: I have provided an answer, but basically there are two overloads, one of which is a const member function, the other is a non-const member function. Then you call `begin()` on a non-const object, it will pick up the non-const version and return an `iterator`, when you call `begin()` on a const map it will pick up the const version and return a `const_iterator`.

Comment: @Pig Head and @Tamas : Read the edit. I added one more sentence : That is because `mymap` is `const` in the function where you've written this.

Comment: I was the downvoter, but since the edit I undone my downvote. I downvoted because the original answer didn't help with understanding the problem.

Comment: @Tamas: I added now full explanation. :-)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `mymap` in the code above is a constant map, not a mutable map (maybe it is a member of a class and that code is inside constant member function?). Thus the call to `mymap.begin()` will pichup the overload that returns a `const_iterator` instead of the overload that returns an `iterator`.

If you do not need to change the container through the iterator, use `const_iterator`. If you intend on modifying the map, make sure that you are using a non-const object for the loop (maybe the member function (if that is the case) should not be const?)